# Why my windows service is getting stuck?

Tags: c#, windows-services, ninject

I have created a windows service which gets stuck when executing this part of the code

```
  Kernel.Bind(x => x.From(assembly)
                           .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom(typeof(CciConstraint))
                           .BindToSelf()
                           .Configure(b => b.InScope(context => context.Parameters.First().GetValue(context, context.Request.Target))));
```

where CciConstraint is an abstract class.

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stuck". If you attach a debugger to the windows service process (In Visual Studio, go to Debug -> Attach to Process..) and put a breakpoint on that line, what happens? Is an exception thrown? Timeout?

Comment: Also Kernel.Bind looks like ninject but the tag is nhibernate.

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to exception.
Whenever any unhandled error or exception occur service gets stop or stuck.

Check your error handling code.